# Form submit not working in bootstrap custom radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap3 for my site..I have to implement custom radio buttons. I implemented custom radio buttons and styling is looking fine using bootstrap3 button styles. The working demo is [here](http://www.bootply.com/123362) But, on submitting the radio button which is checked is not passing through the form which can be seen on clicking submit in demo. I am always getting 'undefined'.The radio button group itself is not submitting it's value.

Though radio buttons are hidden the form values should submit..But not sure why it is not submitting hidden radio button values..

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead..

```
$('input[name=year]:checked').val()
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/123377

Comment: This will work..Thanks.But what if user normally submits the form i.e., without submitting from JS. On normal submission the values are not passing in request.

Comment: The values (name=value) will also be passed accordingly with what's been "checked".. For example, when `$(this).serialize()` is used to get the form values it correctly gets `year=xxxx`.. this would be the same values passed normally with form submit.